# Array Rotation with Getting Max Value and Index Location of Array C language

Tags: arrays, c, function, rotation

I'm creating a program that gets the index value of the highest element in an array.

**Sample Input:**

```
4 (Size of a[])
1 2 4 3 (Elements of a[])
2 (Size of rotate[])
0 2 (Elemnts of rotate[])
```

**Output** will be:

```
2
0
```

Using left rotation.
In the First Rotation (0) the location will be 2 because 4 is the highest a[1,2,4,3]
In the Second Rotation (2) the location will be 0 because 4 is the highest a[4,3,1,2]

Problem is i'm not getting the desired output and there was a warning in `for(j=0;j<rotateValue;j++)`

I want the function to be as it is and to fix this part to `int* output = getMaxIndex(a,rotate);`
but i don't know how.
Thank you in advance for helping!

```
#include<stdio.h>

int i,j,k; // for looping
int n, m; // sizes of arrays


int getMaxIndex(int* a[], int* rotate[])
{
    int indices[m]; 

                
    for(i=0;i<m;i++)
    {
        int* rotateValue = rotate[i];                           
        for(j=0;j<rotateValue;j++)      // for rotation
        {               
            int* first = a[0];  
            for(i=0;i<n-1;i++)
            {       
                a[i] = a[i+1];
            }
            a[n-1] = first;
        }
                
        int location;
        int* max = a[0];
        for(j=0;j<n;j++) // getting the max element 
        {
            if(a[j] > max)
            {
                max = a[j];
//              printf("Max added");
            }
        }
        
        for(j=0;j<n;j++) // getting the location
        {
            if(max == a[j])
            {
                location = j;
//              printf("Loc added");
            }
        }
        
        
        indices[i] = location;      
    

    }
    
//  for(i=0;i<m;i++) // printing here to know if correct
//  {
//      printf("%d",indices[i]);
//  }
    
    
    
    return *indices;
            
        
    

}

int main()
{
    
    
    scanf("%d",&n); // inputting array size 
    int* a[n];  
    
    for(i=0;i<n;i++) // filling elements of a[]
    {
        scanf("%d",&a[i]);
    }
    
    scanf("%d",&m); // inputting rotate array size
    int* rotate[m];
    
    for(i=0;i<m;i++) // filling elements of rotate[]
    {
        scanf("%d",&rotate[i]);
    }
    

    int* output = getMaxIndex(a,rotate); // call function
    
    for(i=0;i<m;i++) // printing output
    {
        printf("%d",output[i]);
    }
    
}


int getMaxIndex(int* a[], int* rotate[]);
```

Comment: " i'm not getting the desired output" Then what do you get?

Comment: "there was a warning" Which one?

Comment: You declare `int* a[n];` i.e. an array of pointers to int. Later, as far as I can tell, you are using it like an array of int. E.g. scan ints into it. Also accordign to its head/prototype your `getMaxIndex()` returns an int (the first one from ìndices`), but you assign it to a pointer to int.  Are you comfortable with the difference of int and pointer to int?

Comment: @Andrywin Maquinto It is entirely unclear what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Yunnoch Hi Im terribly sorry. Im getting a warning at rotateValue. Int point without a cast. What im getting is 0 0

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow It is just a simple array rotation game.

Comment: Hello guys pls go easy on me. Just a beginner. It takes me almost 3hour and I still didnt get it. Im having problems with functions that returns array.

Comment: @AndrywinMaquinto, check out my **edited** answer and adjust your code in main function accordingly. there are a lot of issues with the code and I think all of them originated from how you choose to return the array from the function. And so I've only addressed that issue. If you face any more problem or if you can't undestand the answer let me know in the comment section of my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Designing `getMaxIndex()` in the following way should solve most of the issues:

```c
int* getMaxIndex(int a[], int rotate[])
{
    static int indices[MAX_POSSIBLE_VALUE_OF_M];
    /*
        your code
    */
    return indices;
}
```

Now, all you have to do is adjust your code in the `main()` function accordingly.

---

**Why declare the array `indices[]` in `getMaxIndex()` as static int?**

`indices[]` is a local variable of `getMaxIndex()`. And so after the return statement of `getMaxIndex()` is executed, it shall be destroyed. That means, if you return `indices[]` to `main()`, the main function will not be able to access `indices[]` anymore. And this issue can be solved by declaring `indices[]` as a `static int` instead of `int`.

**NOTE:** static array should have constant size. So, its size should be declared as maximum possible value of m instead of m.

**Required adjustments in `main()`:**

Declare `a[]` and `rotate[]` as `int` instead of `int*`.

Answer (score 0):

Check out my code.I am getting the correct output. I have written down a few mistakes that you have made.

```c
void getMaxIndex(); //function declaration
int n, m; //for storing array size
int * a, * rotate;
int main(void) {

    int i; //to use in loops

    scanf("%d", & n); // inputting array size
    a = (int * ) malloc(n * sizeof(int));

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) // filling elements of a[]
    {
        scanf("%d", & a[i]);
    }

    scanf("%d", & m); // inputting rotate array size
    rotate = (int * ) malloc(m * sizeof(int));

    for (i = 0; i < m; i++) // filling elements of rotate[]
    {
        scanf("%d", & rotate[i]);
    }

    getMaxIndex();

    free(a);
    free(rotate);
    return 0;
}

void getMaxIndex() {
    int i;
    int aMax, rotateMax;
    int aMaxIndex, rotateMaxIndex;
    aMax = a[0];
    rotateMax = rotate[0];

    for (i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        if (aMax < a[i]) {
            aMax = a[i];
            aMaxIndex = i;
        }
    }
    for (i = 1; i < m; i++) {
        if (rotateMax < rotate[i]) {
            rotateMax = rotate[i];
            rotateMaxIndex = i;
        }
    }
    printf("%d\n%d", aMaxIndex, rotateMaxIndex);
}
```

My suggestions:

1. Always try to allocate memory for your array dynamically so that you can avoid errors such as Segmentation Fault or Core Dump.
2. In your code you have used array of pointers instead of pointers, there you went wrong. Try refering to your textbook or other sources to get a clear idea regarding pointers.
   For example, in your code you passed your array named indices using the line:
   return *indices;
   Now, to pass a pointer you don't need to use asterisk(*). Simply write: return indices;
3. Also, don't use asterisk symbol to declare an array.
   Your Code:
   int* a[n];
   Here you are declaring an array of pointers not an array.
   Correct code:
   int a[n];

But I liked your logic. You just have to implement it with the correct syntax. Just keep practicing.
I the code which I've written is understood by you, my work here is done. Happy Coding!!!

Comment: Hi Thank you for your answer. Really appreciate it! and yeah i get an error segmentation fault sometimes ```a = (int * ) malloc(n * sizeof(int))``` is this code making ```int *a``` an array?

Comment: Yes after that line of code you can use a as an array directly!